# notifyItemRangeChanged weird order of item changes?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm building an app in Kotlin using a CardView in RecyclerView, and I need to implement a selection functionality. Selecting works flawlessly, but when I want to reset the view, it behaves weird

This is my function called in onClickListener of a button:

```
private fun resetSelection() {
    viewModel.selectedCards = mutableListOf<Card>()
    viewModel.numOfCards.value = 0
    
    binding.recyclerView.adapter?.itemCount?.let {
        binding.recyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemRangeChanged(0,
            it, "RESET")
    }
}
```

And this is my onBindViewHolder:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, payloads: List<Any>) {

    holder.tv.text = allCards.get(position).description
    holder.iv.setImageBitmap(allCards.get(position).imageUri) 
    
    if (!payloads.isEmpty()) {
        for (a : Any in payloads) {
            if (a.equals("RESET")) {
                holder.ch.visibility = View.GONE
                holder.iv.clearColorFilter()
            }
        }
    } else {
        holder.tv.text = allCards.get(position).description
        holder.iv.setImageBitmap(allCards.get(position).imageUri)

        holder.view.setOnLongClickListener {
            if (addCardToList(allCards.get(position))) {
                val greyFilter =
                    PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF6F00"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)
                holder.iv.setColorFilter(greyFilter)
                holder.ch.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                holder.ch.visibility = View.GONE
                holder.iv.clearColorFilter()
            }
            true
        }
    }
    
}
```

The problem is, whenever calling the function, items are changed in a weird order. Sometimes it's 7, and then 0-6, sometimes it's 1, and then 0-7 excluding the one. I suppose this makes my selection bug out on first and last item, leaving it selected.